# Using pandas dataframe to fit data for a graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, typeerror

Here is some examples of my data before I start explaining:

```
 PP04-O3N2SNpos log(O/H) + 12   positive error! negative error! nuclear metallicity NED calculated virgo infall distance in Kpc
  9.04                          0.24           -0.09             -                  -
  8.76                          0.17           -0.02             -                  4.61
  8.92                          0.04           -0.04             9.03               2.97297
  9.22                          0.04           -0.04             -                  8.24493
  8.78                          0.44           -0.24             9.23               10.25775
  8.96                          0.07           -0.2              9.05               7.2698
  8.78                          0.03           -0.03             8.48               2.02958
```

So the PP04 is the metallicity at the NED calculated distance away from the center and the nuclear metallicity is the metallicity at the center. I'm trying to find out if there is some equation that if I knew the nuclear metallicity and distance from center, I could figure out the PP04. It would look like this:

```
'PP04' - 'nuclear metallicity' = distance * gradient
```

where the gradient is what I am looking for.

To do this I wrote a code to fit all the data so the nuclear metallicity is zero and then I can solve for a gradient and graph the data but I am having a few problems with my code.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import *
 from matplotlib import *
 import traceback
 import numpy as np

 #import data into a pandas dataframe called df
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('Combined data.csv')
 df = df.dropna()
 #drop the nulls
 print df
 y = df['PP04-O3N2SNpos log(O/H)+12'] - df['nuclear metallicity']
 yerr = np.array([(df['negative error!'],df['positive error!'])]).T
 x = df['NED calculated virgo infall distance in Kpc']
 intercept, gradient = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
 print(intercept,gradient)

 #to make a graph using the data
 plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr,fmt = 'r-')
 plt.xlabel('Distance from center in kpc')
 plt.ylabel('PP04-O3N2SNpos log(O/H)+12')
 plt.title('Central metallicity vs SN metallicity')
 plt.show()
```

Another error I get this one

```
 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

I am really new to python so I'm sure there are other things wrong with my code and if you can help with that too it would be appreciated. I'm not sure if the way I wrote plotting the data is correct but I cannot check with the other errors.

**EDIT:**
I used the help below to change my code so now it is using

```
 pd.read_csv('Combined data.csv').dtypes
 pd.read_csv('Combined data.csv',na_values = '-').dtypes
 df = pd.read_csv('Combined data.csv',na_values = '-')
```

But now I'm getting the error

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

Here is the traceback.

[image]

Comment: 1) Clearly the `KeyError` is not happening when you get the traceback shown above, so it means that you sorted out whatever caused it. Maybe it would make sense to remove it from the question. 2) The error seems to suggest that your `x` array contains strings rather than floats. Check the type on the last column and convert if necessary.

Comment: My guess is that the hyphens that stand for the missing values might have prevented `pandas` from converting the column to floats. Try using the `na_values` parameter of `read_csv`.

Comment: The reason the KeyError isn't happening in the traceback was because I deleted the part that said df['nuclear metallicity'] to see if the other df were getting errors too but then I got the above error. So I am still having the KeyError but I guess I should have made it more clear. Thanks for help and I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: In any case it's better to ask about one programming problem per question. You can try printing `df.columns` to see if there is any whitespace in column names or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I used what you suggested below to make the hypens as NaN substitutes but I am still getting an error that I think is related.  I edited my answer above to reflect my changes.

Comment: 1) You don't need to read the file three times... I did it in an interactive session to demonstrate the effect of `na_values`. It doesn't make sense to do it in a script. 2) Print `df.dtypes` and see what's going on. "Nuclear metallicity" is (presumably) still not float. Try printing it to find the reason, maybe some other `na_values` are in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have hyphens in your file, they probably prevent `pandas` from recognizing the columns as numbers. You can tell it to treat hyphens as NaN substitutes using the `na_values` parameter to `read_csv`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: %cat test.csv
a,b
0,-
-,1

In [3]: pd.read_csv('test.csv').dtypes
Out[3]:
a    object
b    object
dtype: object

In [4]: pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values='-').dtypes
Out[4]:
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object

In [5]: pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values='-')
Out[5]:
    a   b
0   0 NaN
1 NaN   1
```